# how to add new changes to live site without redoing everything

Tags: users, importing-exporting, features

I have a site which is running on a huge userbase. The site is about taking online courses and getting certificates.

I am using [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) which adds some extra fields in user profiles.

Also i am using [webforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) to create nodes with questions and answers. Users do some webforms exercises, then take the exam(webforms) and get the certificate.

There is only one custom table which is keeping track of user activity and status.

Now i have been working on a dev site and made lot of changes. What will be the best way to transfer these changes to live site. ?

I tried features module and exported content types and views. After enabling the feature some fields in the content types were not changed ( e.g the field type is text on live site, i changed it to a entity reference in dev site + features will not [delete](https://www.drupal.org/node/649298#comment-7710069) fields). ( and same case with views)

Its not easy to track which changes i have made on dev site. How can i import the users from live site (with all their webforms submissions + profile2 updates + whatnot) to the dev site? Or i should go to doing the changes on live site again ?

Thank you.